# WP Timthumb path error - possibly cache related?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path-finding

I copied a subdomain (actividades.acropolis.org.mx) with a wp install from one server to another. Long story short, while I made the transfer and the DNS for the domain had not been yet redirected to the new server, I used my server's preview URL which was:

http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx.s160231.gridserver.com

Now that the DNS transfer is over, I changed the two rows in the wp_options table that had the url above to the new one: actividades.acropolis.org.mx

EVERYTHING works ok EXCEPT for timthumb.php's pathing.

My suspicion is that it somehow stored the previous url before the dns change took place and is now using that which leads to problems...

This can be seen in the homepage

http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx/actividades/

where the sliding gallery is devoid of thumb images save for a handful (for some odd reason, this handful has a proper pathing even if its very long)

If you fetch the source for the missing images, you get for example:

http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx/wp-content/themes/eVid/timthumb.php?src=http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx.s160231.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/EL-ARTE-DE-VIVIR_EL-ARTE-DE-SERVIR.jpg&h=277&w=858&q=80&zc=1

which leads to an error

So I can't help but wonder how to set the pathing timthumb uses to the correct one.

Regards
Sotkra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timthumb.php was within themes/eVid/

So I went to the admin panel, disabled evid as a theme, enabled the standard twentyeleven theme, disabled it and re-enabled eVid... bam, it updated its filepaths and now everything works perfectly.